# Card Flip: Make flip side height and width auto

Tags: css, hover, flip

I'm trying to make a card flip and am having some problems with the imagery and flip side.

Currently I have to denote the width and height of the div which causes the image to stretch and distort - I want the image be fixed to it's specific aspect ratio. I also want to the width and height of the flip side (yellow side) to be the same as the image. Currently it's the height of the text.

codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XvXJgd

Any help would be much appreciated.

```css
    body {
    font-family: arial;
    padding: 20px;
    }

    .card__container {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    float: left;

    }
    .card {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    width: 100%;
  
    }
    .card:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .card .side {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
  
    }

    .card .side__back {
    border-radius: 26px;
    background: yellow;
    color:white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px grey;
      box-shadow:
        inset 0 0 3px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4),
        inset 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4),
        inset 0 0 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.05),
        2px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    font-size:3vw;
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }

    .card .side img {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    }
```

```html
  <!-- Card container-->
      <div class="card__container">
 <!-- Card -->
 <div class="card">
  <!-- Front side -->
  <div class="side side__front">
   <img src="https://images.uline.com/is/image//content/dam/images/HD/HD8500/HD10_8153.jpg?$UtilityRHD$&iccEmbed=1&icc=AdobeRGB">
  </div>
  <!-- end front side  -->
  <div class="side side__back">
        Lumpy Stool
  </div>
  <!-- end back side  -->
 </div>
 <!-- end card  -->
       </div>

      <!-- Card container-->
      <div class="card__container">
 <!-- Card -->
 <div class="card">
  <!-- Front side -->
  <div class="side side__front">
   <img 
       src="https://images.uline.com/is/image/content/dam/images/Class-Group/c03/c_g60.jpg?&qlt=80&wid=640&hei=440&op_usm=1,1,1&iccEmbed=1&icc=AdobeRGB">
  </div>
  <!-- end front side  -->
    <div class="side side__back">
     Lumpy Stool
    </div> 
    <!-- end back side  -->
    </div>
    <!-- end card  -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your Fiddle and there are some essential changes I have noticed. Those are:

1. You have used float for some element and flex for some elements. Try to remain constant in your project. Either use Float or Flex. My preference is always Flex.
2. You have given height and width for all elements. This can cause an issue for responsive designs. Set width and height of an element to 100% and fix the width and height of parent of that element. So that if changes are required for responsive design you don't need to change width and height everywhere.
3. Absolute positioned element does not have its own width and height so you have to specify its width and height. For that again refer point 2

I have done some changes in your fiddle to solve your issue. I have added parent class named wrapper for card__container element. Changes are: CSS :

```
body {
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;  
}

.card__container { 
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.card {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .side {
  height: 250px;
   width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.card .side__back {
  border-radius: 26px;
  background: yellow;
  color:white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px grey;
      box-shadow:
        inset 0 0 3px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4),
        inset 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4),
        inset 0 0 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.05),
        2px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  font-size:3vw;
   display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card .side img {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
    border-radius: 26px;
}
```